# How can I construct a pairwise distance matrix using a custom metric (set distance)?

Tags: python, matrix, data-science, bioinformatics

I would like to create a program that computes a distance matrix from the results of my calculations on sets. Data about these sets is taken from a file.
I currently have something like the code below, but maybe my idea is quite bad and it can be improved (e.g. collections only listed, not ordered).

```
my_list = []
file = open("plik.txt","r")

for i in file:
    my_sets = i.split(", ")
    A = set(my_sets[0])
    B = set(my_sets[1])
    a = len(A.difference(B))
    b = len(B.difference(A))
    c = len(A.union(B))
    metric = (a*b)/c
    my_list.append(round(metric, 2))

print(my_list)
file.close()
```

As an example, imagine that I have in a file something like this (all combinations for 4 sets):

```
set1 set2
set1 set3
set1 set4
set2 set3
set2 set4
set3 set4
```

Now, examples of values for the resulting metric could be:

`[0.8, 1.2, 4.3, 5, 7, 0.2]`

I want to get a 4x4 matrix matrix out of it, containing the metric for all pairs:

```
[[0, 0.8, 1.2, 4.3],
[0.8, 0, 5, 7],
[1.2, 5, 0, 0.2],
[4.3, 7, 0.2, 0]]
```

How should I transform the list of values of the metric obtained for the pairs so to obtain the distance matrix?

Comment: Feels like there’s something else you could post. Could you describe in words how a distance matrix is calculated from a list. For example, how the matrix entry m(i,j) might depend on the list.

Comment: Ok, I will try to write more and i will attach the code.

Comment: It is very possible that I am getting to this task badly. Sorry for the code, but I pasted the sketch quickly. I will edit it soon. Maybe from the beginning i will explain the assumption of the project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computation of the distance is not expensive, I would refactor your code as follows (I am improvising a reproducible example for illustrative purposes, and you can skip the `my_sets` creation bit)

Given a `plik.txt` file containing a column of sets as this:

```
my_sets
ABCD
EFGD
AGID
ZWHK
```

you can read it in and transform it into sets with

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("plik.txt")

my_sets = data.my_sets.apply(set).to_list()
```

I now have `my_sets`, a list of 4 sets (of letters, but they could be anything):

```
 [{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
 {'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'},
 {'A', 'D', 'G', 'I'},
 {'H', 'K', 'W', 'Z'}]
```

and for each pair of elements, I can compute a distance that you defined using set operations as

```
def dist(a, b) : return len(a.difference(b))*len(b.difference(a))/len(a.union(b))
```

To create a simple symmetric matrix of pairwise distances between the sets in `my_sets`, a simple way is a nested `for` loop:

```
N = len(my_sets)

pdist = np.zeros((N, N)) # I have imported numpy as np above!

for i in range(N):
  for j in range(i + 1, N):
    pdist[i,j] = dist(my_sets[i], my_sets[j])
    pdist[j,i] = pdist[i,j]
```

`pdist` should be the symmetric matrix you're looking for, and gets filled in N*(N-1)/2 operations (the combinations of N elements in pairs).

Comment: I tried to sketch an answer based on some assumptions, not sure it's on point but I hope that can be helpful. Some ideas are 1) you can use a dedicated library like pandas to read in your data 2) there's no need to compute the pairwise distance for all combinations and reshape the list into a matrix, one can construct the matrix element by element.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm just starting the adventure and you helped me a lot! :)